# Problemas al coger parametros de una imagen cargada desde el equipo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Mi Pagina.html es asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/miestilos.css">
<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input type="file" id="files"  />
    <output id="list"></output>
</div>
<div id="altura">Altura</div>
<div id="anchura">Anchura</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src= "js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi script es este:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 function handleFileSelect(evt) {
 var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

 // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
 for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

  // Only process image files.
  if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
    continue;
  }

  var reader = new FileReader();

  // Closure to capture the file information.
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
      // Render thumbnail.
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      document.getElementById('list').innerHTML='';
      span.innerHTML = ['<img class="center" id="imagen" src="', e.target.result,
                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');


      document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };

  })(f);


  // Read in the image file as a data URL.
  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
 }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);



 });
```

Al coger una imagen me la muestra correctamente y me la inserta en el codigo.

Lo que quiero saber es que cuando carge la imagen donde pone altura y anchura quiero que me muestre la anchura y altura de la imagen pero no puedo coger los parametros de la imagen.

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando tu mismo código solo agregue un par de lineas. Lo primero que hice fue buscar la imagen ya creada por el **id** que le colocaste "imagen justo después de que la renderizastes, porque si lo coloco antes la imagen no existe y no puedo obtener sus medidas, así:

```
document.getElementById('imagen')
```

Luego le asigne un evento **load** para cuando este cargada completamente ahi pueda obtener sus medias con el `this.height` y `this.width`:

```
document.getElementById('imagen').addEventListener('load', function(e) { 

  document.getElementById('altura').innerHTML = "Altura: "+this.height;
  document.getElementById('anchura').innerHTML = "Anchura: "+this.width;

});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
 
    var files = evt.target.files; 
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {

      return function(e) {
      
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML='';
        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="center" id="imagen" src="', e.target.result,'" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        document.getElementById('imagen').addEventListener('load', function(e) { 
              
              document.getElementById('altura').innerHTML = "Altura: "+this.height;
              document.getElementById('anchura').innerHTML = "Anchura: "+this.width;
            })
        
      };

    })(f);

    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    
  }}

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <input type="file" id="files"  />
    <output id="list"></output>
</div>
<div id="altura">Altura</div>
<div id="anchura">Anchura</div>
```

Espero que te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que yo lo hago de otra manera. Si necesitas una solución este es mi código. Por favor lea los comentarios en el código.

```js
// cuando el input nuevaImagen cambia
nuevaImagen.addEventListener("change",function(event) {
   // una expresion regular para validar que el tipo de fichero es una imagen 
   var esImagen = /^image\//;
   // si el archivo es de tipo imagen   
   if (esImagen.test(event.target.files[0].type)) {
       
  // crea un nuevo elemento img  que todavía no pertenece al DOM
  var imagen = new Image();
  imagen.src = 
    window.URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

// cuando la imagen esté cargada
  imagen.onload = function(){
  //agrega la imagen al DOM
   la_imagen.appendChild(imagen);
   
   altura.innerHTML = imagen.height;
   anchura.innerHTML = imagen.width;
  }
   
}
})
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id='nuevaImagen' type="file"  />
</form>
<div id="la_imagen"></div>
<div>Altura: <span id="altura"></span></div>
<div>Anchura: <span id="anchura"></span></div>
```